# Make git print a unified diff between two given commit

Tags: git, diff

Also, how to refer to the commits? Hopefully I don't have to type those
terrible hash-strings!

Comment: Exactly what don't you understand from the "git diff" man page? It links to the way you specify revisions too, which has tons of examples.

Comment: Didn't want to be rude! :-) Just, are diffs unified by default? And, does HEAD refer to a branch, or to the tip of the branch?

Comment: _Are diffs unified by default?_ You could check that by running it. "branch head" in git refers to the the most recent commit of a branch - and branches track only that, so there's no real difference. You would benefit from reading at least the first few chapters of the [user manual](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/user-manual.html), to get the concepts right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
git diff <commit> <commit>
```

See also:

- http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html
- http://learn.github.com/p/diff.html

> The ‘diff’ command in Git will show you the same thing - the changes between two snapshots or files *in unified diff* format.